# Создание онлайн-компилятора на django

Tags: python-3.x, django, веб-программирование

Как правильно создать онлайн комплиятор языка Си? Есть текстовая форма текст из которой записывается в текстовый файл, как грамотно запустить после этого компилятор си? Как сделать так чтобы код не мог ничего менять на сервере (только получать инпут и возвращать результаты)? Может есть примеры, подскажите пожалуйста (вузовский проект)

Comment: покажите, что вы сами пытались сделать, в чем конкретно возникли сложности. мы здесь не делаем за вас вашу работу, тем более учебную.

Comment: но вообще, делая скидку на то, что вы новичок, скажу, что имхо вам надо смотреть в сторону выполнения консольных команд на питоне. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html  посмотрите этот пакет.

Comment: @СергейКоновалов да у меня вопрос больше о том, как запретить си коду что-то менять на сервере? ограничить комплитор как-то или что лучше сделать?

Comment: запускайте его из-под отдельного юзера, имеющего очень ограниченные права.

Comment: хм, в модуле который вы скинули есть такие возможности, попробую, спасибо) насколько это безопасно будет? (уж в ос совсем плохо, базовые знания линукс администрирования есть)

Comment: очень безопасно, если вы будете выполнять команду от юзера с правами только на выполнение этой команды

Comment: @СергейКоновалов Не, тут надо sandbox создать. ИМХО просто юзера не достаточно.

Comment: @СергейКоновалов уже прошло чутка времени, запускаю все докере отдельно

Comment: @Alice_nvbr докер - это прекрасно